# Save tree to a variable with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm newcomer in C#. And I'm looking for similar function in HtmlAgilityPack. In Python parsing library called BeautifulSoup exist function called [contents](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#contents). How I can done this by means of HtmlAgility?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so first get the document root which has all the contents

```
//create a new document
var _htmlDoc = new  HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

//fill it with html
_htmlDoc.Load(filePath) or _htmlDoc.LoadHtml(string...)

//get the document root node - it has all the contents
var docuemntNode = _htmlDoc.DocumentNode;
```

then...  use linq or xpath to query for nodes

```
string xpathExpressionSting = "//p";
var contents = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpathExpressionSting)
//this would get paragraph tag nodes
```

Comment: Anyone know how to recursively traversing down the HTML document object model, looking for text nodes? I try save all text without tags on the page in .txt file. But instead of 500 lines, I get duplicate 6000 lines. What I'm doing wrong?

    TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("html.txt");
    foreach (HtmlNode text in soup.DocumentNode.Descendants())
    {
        string subText = text.InnerText;
        resultText += subText;
        tw.WriteLine(resultText);  
    }
    tw.Close();

Comment: it looks like the inner text may contain the enclosed nodes as well. I'm not sure. Please ask as a new question

Comment: not sure how to do it recursively, though I think that you could select them all via - var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//text()")  - although I'm not entirely sure about the xpath syntax